# How to draw Bezier curve in flutter

Tags: flutter, bezier, curve

I want to draw the following shape:

[image: How to draw Bezier Curve for Following image..]

I have tried many tutorial But I could find the desired Output. I would appreciate help from you people. thanks

Comment: use `inkscape` free tool to draw it and check svg output (<path> element) - it will contain bezier curve parameters

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials available on the net you can get what you get just do hit and trials first. and please provide some more insight before asking questions